# Upgrade python in a virtual environment with '-m venv --upgrade'

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have multiple python versions managed by pyenv. I want to upgrade one of my virtual environments from 3.7.13 to 3.10.3 with the ‘—upgrade’ option as:

```
>deactivate 
>pyenv local 3.10.3 
>python3 -m venv --upgrade .venv 
>. .venv/bin/activate 
> python -V 
Python 3.7.13
```

I expect the '—upgrade' would change the python version to 3.10.3 but it did not it stayed with 3.7.13

I understand it may be easier just discard and recreate the virtual environment, but I really want to learn how '—upgrade' should work

Comment: I'm letting you know that I was able to reproduce this behavior using a fresh install, so it's not just you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read [the official documentation of the `venv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), then the description of the --upgrade option is very specific: "... assuming Python has been upgraded in-place." I think this implies that it has to be the same Python installation that you originally created the virtual environment with, for the `--upgrade` flag to work. Each version of Python installed by pyenv is installed separately, so I wouldn't expect the `--upgrade` flag to work in this case.

That being said, as far as I know, `venv` does little more than installing a couple of basic scripts and configuration files, and some bunch of symbolic links. The [source code of the `venv` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Lib/venv) seems fairly straightforward, and all that the `--upgrade` switch does is skip the setup scripts. I think you could manually "hack" your way through this by changing some symbolic links and changing some directory names here and there. However, it's not how `venv` should be used.

So, yeah, save yourself the misery, and discard the old virtual environment and just build a new one.

Comment: I finally understand what *"assuming Python has been upgraded in-place"* means, but that isn't the way most users use Python environments. For example I had 2 local directories with Python 3.9 and 3.10, and now that I created a new directory with Python 3.11 I would need a `venv` option to make an existing environment using Python 3.9 point to Python 3.11. Of course I could *upgrade in place* Python 3.9 to Python 3.11 but guess what, the name of directory with Python 3.9 is `.localpython39` so would be misleading to have Python3.11 inside it, and I have to recreate from stratch the environment

Comment: @mmj Actually, I would expect most people to only have one global Python installation, with packages installed globally, or packages installed locally using virtual environments created with `venv`. So, when those users upgrade their global Python installation to a newer Python version, they can "fix" their old virtual environments by using venv's `--upgrade` flag.

Comment: @mmj However, pyenv forces you to work in a way that is different. As far as I know, pyenv does not support upgrading its Python installations to newer versions in the traditional sense. Instead, if you want to use a newer version with pyenv then you have to create a new separate installation for that newer version of Python, and because this new installation is separate from your old installation, venv's `--upgrade` flag does not work as expected.

Comment: @mmj Another hint that you probably can't do what you want to do, is how pyenv's own `virtualenv` command works. It also creates separate virtual environments for different Python versions, instead of using some magical trick to reuse/upgrade the same virtual environment.

Comment: @mmj It's probably possible to manually upgrade pyenv's installations in-place somehow, or to trick `venv` by editing the files in your virtual environment to point to a different Python installation, but these options seem very error-prone and will probably break stuff unexpectedly. I don't recommend trying this. Instead, create a setup so that you can easily recreate your virtual environment after switching to a different Python version (e.g. using a `requirements.txt` file), and you'll never have to worry about this problem again.

Comment: Indeed that's what I'm doing, recreate environment from stratch with a custom version of python with `~/.localpython3X/bin/python3.X -m venv --clear <env-path>` (which deletes the environment content), then I reinstall all the packages with `pip install <space-reparated-list-of-core-packages>`. (I stopped using `requirements.txt` because when a package drops a dependency, until you discover it  and manually delete it from `requirements.txt`, you keep installing such unused dependent pakcages.)